# Swift array initializer syntax type mismatch

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization, tuples

From Swift Programming Guide:

> You can create an empty array of a certain type using initializer syntax:
>
> ```
> var someInts = [Int]()
> println("someInts is of type [Int] with \(someInts.count) items.")
> // prints "someInts is of type [Int] with 0 items."
> ```
>
> Note that the type of the `someInts` variable is inferred to be `[Int]` from the type of the initializer.

But if you actually copy this as is into XCode, and check the type of `someInts`, you get `[(Int)]`, which is an array of single element `Int` tuples. Why this discrepancy? You can also initialize an array as follows:

```
var someInts: [Int] = []
```

That has the correct type.

Practically these types seem to behave the same, but I'm trying to figure out what's going on here.

Also [in the reference doc for Array](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html) it says:

> Creating an array using this initializer:
>
> ```
> var emptyArray = Array<Int>()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to using the convenience syntax:
>
> ```
> var equivalentEmptyArray = [Int]()
> ```

But `emptyArray` above has the type `Array<Int>` while `equivalentEmptyArray` has type `[(Int)]` as in the previous example. `Array<Int>` is just the full form of `[Int]` though, so this isn't really a problem, except that the latter doesn't match the type the doc says it is.

Note: finding types by option-clicking on the variable or by selecting it and looking in the Quick Help Inspector in the right side menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `[Int]` and `[(Int)]` actually behave exactly the same (in fact they are the same).

Unfortunately I don't know the exact reason why this is happening but as of Xcode 7 beta 5 (and probably earlier versions) it only shows the type as `[Int]`.